# App Crashing when changing activity

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-activity

My app crashes when changing activity Here is my code,
I was following a tutorial on youtube, Everything seems to be exactly like his code. See if you can help
Everything seems to be inorder, I copyed everything exactly,

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.helloworld.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                counter++;
                display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                counter--;
                display.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Splash.java:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Splash extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.helloworld.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                }
            }
        };  
        timer.start();
    }
}




Logcat:

07-19 20:35:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-74
07-19 20:35:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.helloworld.MAINACTIVITY }
07-19 20:35:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
07-19 20:35:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
07-19 20:35:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
07-19 20:35:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
07-19 20:35:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.example.helloworld.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:23)
```

Comment: please post the logcat error message associated with the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.helloworld.MAINACTIVITY");
```

To:

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: Worked, Thanks, The tutorial was designed for 2.2, and I am using 4.0.3, could that be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so. 4.0.3 should be completely backwards compatible. Please accept the answer if it worked out for you. =)

Comment: Its not working because you have a typo in your Manifest. The category has to be DEFAULT. The system tests against all components you describe inside a intent-filter and only if all tests return true it uses this activity to handle your intent EDIT: see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs

Answer (score -1):

I think the application crashes because you misspelled "DEFAULT" in the intent-filter.